# What does "weak-field limit" mean when it refer to dipole and atomic polarization?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, polarization, dipole

In Griffiths' book, *Introduction to Electrodynamics 3rd*, problem 4.3,it requires me to find the condition on ρ(r) such that equation $p = αE$ will hold in the weak-field limit. The answer gives $ρ（r）=Ar$, and i don't understand why, either that it requires $p$ is proportional to $E$ while the answer gives $E^{1/2}$,is it because of the weak-field limit? And why the answer requires $E$ to be proportional to $r$ and $ρ$ to be zero at the origin?

> $$p=αE     \tag{4.1}\label{}$$       α means atomic polarization
>
> Question:
> Problem 4.3 According to Eq. 4.1， the induced dipole moment of an atom is proportional to the external field. This is a"rule of thumb not a fundamental law, and it is easy to concoct exceptions--in theory. Suppose, for example, the charge density of the electron cloud were proportional to the distance from the center, out to a radius $R$. To what power of E would p be proportional in that case？ Find the condition on ρ（r） such that Eq. 4.1 will hold in the weak-field limit
>
> Answer:
> ρ（r）=Ar. Electric field（ by Gauss's Law：$$∮E·da=E（4πr²）=Q/(ε₀),or E=(Ar²)/(4ε₀)$$
> This “internal” field balances the external field $E$ when nucleus is “off-center” an amount
> $$d:(ad²)/(4ε₀)=E⇨d={\sqrt {(4ε₀E)/A}}$$So the induced dipole moment is $$p= ed= 2e·{\sqrt {ε₀/A}}E^{1/2}$$ Evidently p is proportional to $E^{1/2}$.
> For Eq. 4.1 to hold in the weak-field limit, E must be proportional to r, for small r, which means that ρ must go to a constant（not zero）at the origin:ρ（0）≠0（nor infinite）

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most systems have $p$ proportional to $E$ for small $E$. The example from Griffiths is meant to illustrate an *exception* to that general pattern, hence they pick a specific distribution of charge so that $p\propto E^{1/2}$, which is not proportional to $E$.

The second part of the question asks for what exactly makes some distributions $\rho$ give a linear dependence and some do not. The answer is that the density at $0$ needs to be nonzero. The distribution with $\rho\propto r$ is zero at $r=0$, so the polarization is not proportional to $E$.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has 2 questions.

The 1st is : if ρ=Ar , the relation between **E** and **p**.

The 2ed is : if I want p=αE , how to solve ρ?

Lets solve 2ed question:

Assume ρ=B  (B is a constant）.

∮E⋅da=E（4πr²）=Q/(ε₀)=∫B4πr²dr/(ε₀)  .

We can solve：

E=Br/3(ε₀)，

so r=3(ε₀)E/B,

so p=qr=3q(ε₀)E/B，

then we can see p is proportional to E.

So we can see if ρ=B(the charge density is a constant），p is proportional to E.